# BindingSource with comboboxes using autocomplete

Tags: vb.net

Please, I'm using vb.net ultimate 2013 and I have about 15 comboboxes being populated with data at runtime.
Now, I used a "for loop"to add autocomplete feature to the comboboxes and it takes a longer time to load the form as a  result of the "for loop", looping through each combo box to add the autocomplete feature. I thought of  a binding source but how to implement it becomes a problem. Is there any quick way to to add the auto complete feature at runtime? That's my code below.

```
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = DataL1
    SqlQuery = "Select * from Users order by  UserName asc"
    dSet1 = New DataSet : dSet2 = New DataSet : dSet3 = New DataSet : dSet4 = New DataSet
    dSet5 = New DataSet : dSet6 = New DataSet : dSet7 = New DataSet : dSet8 = New DataSet
    dSet9 = New DataSet : dSet10 = New DataSet : dSet11 = New DataSet : dSet12 = New DataSet
    dSet13 = New DataSet : dSet14 = New DataSet : dSet15 = New DataSet
    dTable = New DataSet
    daAdapterRec = New SqlDataAdapter
    daAdapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter2 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter3 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter4 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon)
    daAdapter5 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter6 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter7 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter8 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon)
    daAdapter9 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter10 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter11 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter12 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon)
    daAdapter13 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter14 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon) : daAdapter15 = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon)
    daAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon)
    Try
        daAdapter1.Fill(dSet1, "Users") : daAdapter2.Fill(dSet2, "Users") : daAdapter3.Fill(dSet3, "Users") : daAdapter4.Fill(dSet4, "Users") : daAdapter5.Fill(dSet5, "Users") : daAdapter5.Fill(dSet5, "Users")
        daAdapter6.Fill(dSet6, "Users") : daAdapter7.Fill(dSet7, "Users") : daAdapter8.Fill(dSet8, "Users") : daAdapter9.Fill(dSet9, "Users") : daAdapter10.Fill(dSet10, "Users") : daAdapter11.Fill(dSet11, "Users")
        daAdapter12.Fill(dSet12, "Users") : daAdapter13.Fill(dSet13, "Users") : daAdapter14.Fill(dSet14, "Users") : daAdapter15.Fill(dSet15, "Users")
        daAdapter.Fill(dTable, "Users")
        'From1
        frmtracking.cboFrom1.DataSource = dTable.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboFrom1.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        frmTracking.cboFrom1.Text = frmVisibleNot.txtUsername.Text.Trim

        'To1
        frmtracking.cboTo1.DataSource = dSet1.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo1.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To2
        frmtracking.cboTo2.DataSource = dSet2.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo2.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To3
        frmtracking.cboTo3.DataSource = dSet3.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo3.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To4
        frmtracking.cboTo4.DataSource = dSet4.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo4.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To5
        frmtracking.cboTo5.DataSource = dSet5.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo5.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To6
        frmtracking.cboTo6.DataSource = dSet6.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo6.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To7
        frmtracking.cboTo7.DataSource = dSet7.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo7.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To8
        frmtracking.cboTo8.DataSource = dSet8.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo8.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To9
        frmtracking.cboTo9.DataSource = dSet9.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo9.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To10
        frmtracking.cboTo10.DataSource = dSet10.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo10.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To11
        frmtracking.cboTo11.DataSource = dSet11.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo11.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To12
        frmtracking.cboTo12.DataSource = dSet12.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo12.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        frmtracking.cboTo12.Text = ""
        'To13
        frmtracking.cboTo13.DataSource = dSet13.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo13.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To14
        frmtracking.cboTo14.DataSource = dSet14.Tables("Users")
        frmtracking.cboTo14.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'To15
        frmtracking.cboTo15.DataSource = dSet15.Tables("Users")
        frmTracking.cboTo15.DisplayMember = "UserName"
        'Auto Complete All the Fields
        Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To dTable.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col.Add(dTable.Tables(0).Rows(i)("UserName").ToString.Trim())
            frmTracking.cboTo1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            frmTracking.cboTo1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
            frmTracking.cboTo1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Next

        'Auto Complete All the Fields
        Dim col2 As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim ii As Integer
        For ii = 0 To dSet2.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col2.Add(dSet2.Tables(0).Rows(ii)("UserName").ToString.Trim())
            frmTracking.cboTo2.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            frmTracking.cboTo2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col2
            frmTracking.cboTo2.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Next
        'Auto Complete All the Fields
        Dim col3 As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim iii As Integer
        For iii = 0 To dSet3.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col3.Add(dSet3.Tables(0).Rows(iii)("UserName").ToString.Trim())
            frmTracking.cboTo3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            frmTracking.cboTo3.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col3
            frmTracking.cboTo3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Next
        'Auto Complete All the Fields
        Dim col4 As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim iv As Integer
        For iv = 0 To dSet4.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col4.Add(dSet4.Tables(0).Rows(iv)("UserName").ToString.Trim())
            frmTracking.cboTo4.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            frmTracking.cboTo4.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col4
            frmTracking.cboTo4.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Next
        'Auto Complete All the Fields
        Dim col5 As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim v As Integer
        For v = 0 To dSet5.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col5.Add(dSet5.Tables(0).Rows(v)("UserName").ToString.Trim())
            frmTracking.cboTo5.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            frmTracking.cboTo5.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col5
            frmTracking.cboTo5.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Next
        Dim col6 As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim vi As Integer
        For vi = 0 To dSet6.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col6.Add(dSet6.Tables(0).Rows(vi)("UserName").ToString.Trim())
            frmTracking.cboTo6.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            frmTracking.cboTo6.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col6
            frmTracking.cboTo6.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Next


        Dim col7 As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim vii As Integer
        For vii = 0 To dSet7.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col7.Add(dSet7.Tables(0).Rows(vii)("UserName").ToString.Trim())
            frmTracking.cboTo7.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            frmTracking.cboTo7.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col7
            frmTracking.cboTo7.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Next

        Dim col8 As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim viii As Integer
        For viii = 0 To dSet8.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col8.Add(dSet8.Tables(0).Rows(viii)("UserName").ToString.Trim())
            frmTracking.cboTo8.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            frmTracking.cboTo8.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col8
            frmTracking.cboTo8.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Next

        Dim col9 As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim ix As Integer
        For ix = 0 To dSet9.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col9.Add(dSet9.Tables(0).Rows(ix)("UserName").ToString.Trim())
            frmTracking.cboTo9.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            frmTracking.cboTo9.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col9
            frmTracking.cboTo9.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are repeating your code too much times.
NOT TESTED

```
SQLCon.ConnectionString = DataL1
SqlQuery = "Select * from Users order by  UserName asc"
ds = New DataSet 
da = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SQLCon)
Try
    da.Fill(ds, "Users")
    Dim bs = new BindingSource()
    bs.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    frmtracking.cboFrom1.DataSource = bs

    Dim bs1 = new BindingSource()
    bs1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    frmtracking.cboFrom2.DataSource = bs1

    .... repeat for the other combos


    Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To dTable.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        col.Add(dTable.Tables(0).Rows(i)("UserName").ToString.Trim())
    Next
    frmTracking.cboTo1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    frmTracking.cboTo1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
    frmTracking.cboTo1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest


    frmTracking.cboFrom1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    frmTracking.cboFrom1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
    frmTracking.cboFrom1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

    ... repeat for the other combos
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the comboboxes do not get populated and autocomplete does not work as well. Just getting confused. Please review the code for me

Comment: First check if your da.Fill(ds..) returns some rows in the table. Set a breakpoint after the fill and look for `ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count` value. Then are you sure that the frmTracking variable is an instance of a currently visible form? I suppose that this code is inside some class that receives the variable from an external call. Instead if you are inside  the frmTracking form class then change the reference to Me.cboFrom1 etc....